# Fifth Doctor Who episode with him monologing about how being a time traveller means you don't solve problems like humans

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

There is an episode of *Doctor Who*, the Fifth Doctor, in which he launches into a monologue about who he is and how being a time traveller means you don't solve problems like humans - while he is monologing he casually walks between a pair of (I think) knights sword-fighting, without interruption, as if to demonstrate that point.

The scene is outdoors, during the day, possibly on a lawn and I think he is walking towards the camera from left to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have remembered this moment from the Seventh Doctor story "Battlefield". I don't know what lines of dialogue precede it but the Seventh Doctor at least talked about how linear beings like humans couldn't understand how he, a Time Lord, thinks. At the ending of "Dragonfire", for instance, or during the famous café scene in "Remembrance of the Daleks".

The Fifth Doctor doesn't ever have dialogue like that, at least not on television.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to expand on how this matches?

Comment: I have done so. did you watch the clip? because it shows the Doctor doing just what you said.

Comment: Thank you. I know I didn't watch any Doctor Who at all in the late 1980's - the episode you show was broadcast  September 1989 and to the best of my knowledge I have never seen it.   However that does not mean that my memory has not been scrambled somehow (it definitely has...). I now have a reason to watch this story - will update when I have done so.  :)

Comment: you must have seen this scene at one point or, at least, heard about it, even if you've not seen the entire story. no scene like the one you describes anywhere else in televised <i>Doctor Who</i>.

Comment: I have come around to thinking that this answer is more reliable than my memory, so marking it as such - thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

"[The King's Demons](http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/classic/episodeguide/kingsdemons/)" is the only Fifth Doctor story with a medieval setting.

Comment: Kings Demons is a good suggestion. As it is only two episodes I just watched it through on fast-forward and it certainly looks like the right setting but that scene is not in there. I am fairly sure it was two armoured knights he walked between and not robots. I may have to watch the whole of the fifth doctor again so I can sleep at night. Hmmm....

Comment: You need to edit this to a) elaborate on how it matches because this is very brief and doesn't even say if it matches the main plot element described in the OP and b) fix the link because it's broken and I don't even know what it's supposed to point to, if anything.